# .NET Template - Code in Conditional is Ignored During Compilation

Tags: c#, .net, templates, .net-core

I am trying to create a .NET template for new microservices. I am looking at how code can be conditionally added / removed with [Conditional expressions](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/blob/main/docs/Conditions.md), so that certain parts of the solution like Swagger can be removed if desired. My one issue is, I want to be able to compile and work on the solution so that it can be easily improved on by other people. For example, I have a boolean parameter `EnableSwaggerSupport` that will remove adding swagger in `Startup.cs` if it is not enabled.

```
#if EnableSwaggerSupport
    services.AddSwagger(_environment);
#endif
```

Unfortunately, when trying to compile the solution, it is ignored during compilation. I would have to comment out the `#if` and `#endif` or remove them from `Startup.cs` to continue working on the solution. Since I want to make the solution still compile with or without Swagger (in this example), it would be great if I could decide whether or not to include the code in the template conditionals (`services.AddSwagger(_environment);` in this example) during compilation to ensure that it works with and without that statement removed.

Is there any easy way to get the code in the conditional included during compilation? In my mind, doing something like setting `EnableSwaggerSupport: 'true'` in appSettings.json would make sense, but it doesn't seem possible.

I am working in VS 2022.

I am trying to get the code inside a conditional in my dotnet template solution to compile, but it is ignored during compilation.

Comment: Are you sure it is ignored, or can it be that your logic is flawed? In the given example, you add swagger if it is _not_ enabled

Comment: @king_nak I want to ensure that it works with both the statement included and the statement not included, so that I know it works with `EnableSwaggerSupport` or without `EnableSwaggerSupport`. There also isn't a way to have code included in compilation removed within the template besides using a conditional, as shown as above.

In the given example, the line is ignored during compilation.

Comment: @king_nak you were correct, my logic was flawed.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that this can be fixed by simply flipping the logic, e.g. having `DisableSwaggerSupport` and then having the conditional setup as

```
#if DisableSwaggerSupport
#else
            services.AddSwagger(_environment);
#endif
```

The code within the `else` will be included during compilation.

Answer (score 0):

You could define the `EnableSwaggerSupport` constant in your .csproj file (or in the `Directory.Build.props` for all projects), and wrap it in a `#if (false)` block that only gets [evaluated by the .NET Template Engine](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/wiki/Conditional-processing-and-comment-syntax#msbuild-files):

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net70</TargetFramework>
    <!--#if (false) -->
    <!-- The condition above is evaluated by the .NET Template Engine but not by the Microsoft Build Engine (MSBuild).
         Hence, the properties below will apply when compiling the template itself,
         but will be removed by the .NET Template Engine when creating a project. -->
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);EnableSwaggerSupport</DefineConstants>
    <!--#endif -->
  </PropertyGroup>
```